# ios uiimagview tap gesture not recognised

Tags: ios, uitableview, gesture, tap

The imageview inside tableview cell the tap gesture not working.

following is code.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

            CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(5, 0, 320, 30);
            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame1];
            label.text = @"READ THIS";
            label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
            cell.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:231.0f/255.0f green:234.0f/255.0f blue:235.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];



            UIImageView *downImage =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270,0,35,35)];
            downImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"downimg.png"];
            downImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            downImage.tag = indexPath.row;

            UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myFunction:)];
            tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            [downImage addGestureRecognizer:tapped];

            [label addSubview:downImage];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do set `UserInteractionEnabled` to `YES` for the `UILabel` on which you are adding the `UIImageView` as subview

Property `userInteractionEnabled` is disabled for `UILabel` as well by default.